# How can I configure my (POSIX) socket for VoIP usage on iOS?

Tags: ios, sockets, voip

in Apples "iOS App Programming Guide" under "Tips for Developing a VoIP App" it says how to "Configuring Sockets for VoIP Usage" for NSInputStream, NSURLRequest and CFReadStreamRef. But  my socket is created using the standard "sys/socket.h" within a library I use. How can I configure that?

thanks

Comment: Provide a link to that section of the guide.

Comment: [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW12)

Paragraph "Configuring Sockets for VoIP Usage"

Comment: I am also interested to know this..